# How cache and play video in VideoView on Oreo?

Tags: android, video, libraries, android-videoview

I'm trying to cache a video by link and play it in VideoView
Url: http://52.28.157.12:8080/hosting/video/video%20(4).mp4
(this url work correct)

Tried to use:
https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache 
(work on 25 SDK but not work on 28)

https://github.com/yangwencan2002/MediaLoader 
(work on 25 SDK but not work on 28)

https://github.com/blueflychief/AndriodVideoCache (not work)